# How do I make a dedicated row for javascript alerts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the jsfiddle example below, every time there's an alert it shifts the content below it down a row.  How do I create a blank row dedicated to alerts that will just have the alerts fade in and out without shifting the content below it down?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bayman/XDaEk/320/)

html:

```
<div class="alert-box success">Successful Alert !!!</div>
<div class="alert-box failure">Failure Alert !!!</div>
<div class="alert-box warning">Warning Alert !!!</div>
<hr>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>
    <button id="success-btn">Success</button>
    <button id="failure-btn">Failure</button>
    <button id="warning-btn">Warning</button>
</p>
```

javascript:

```
$( "#success-btn" ).click(function() {
  $( "div.success" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
});

$( "#failure-btn" ).click(function() {
  $( "div.failure" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
});

$( "#warning-btn" ).click(function() {
  $( "div.warning" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
});
```

css:

```
.alert-box {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;  
}

.success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    display: none;
}

.failure {
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    display: none;
}

.warning {
    color: #8a6d3b;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #faebcc;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/XDaEk/322/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a wrapper div with a suffisant heigth.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/kp1j8zat/)

```
<div id="alert-wrapper">
    <div class="alert-box success">Successful Alert !!!</div>
    <div class="alert-box failure">Failure Alert !!!</div>
    <div class="alert-box warning">Warning Alert !!!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#alert-wrapper{
    height:46px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USe visibility: hidden

.alert-box {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;  
}

.success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.failure {
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.warning {
    color: #8a6d3b;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #faebcc;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```